# Visual Studio 2013's Team Explorer showing 700+ Included Changes after fresh clone from git

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I'm working through a strange git problem.  I'm using github and the GitHub Desktop application to clone my repository onto a Windows Professional 7 laptop.

After the clone the GitHub desktop shows no changes in the master branch.

I then open Visual Studio 2013 and it shows no changes for a moment in Team Explorer tab - Changes view.  Then it shows 700+ included changes and when I compare to unmodified, that comparison view shows no changes for any randomly selected file.

What's going on?  This is not every file in my repository, there are close to 5000 files in the repository.

The only none standard option that I did was enable long file names like so:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Does the GitHub desktop app use a different version of git than Visual Studio is using?

Comment: I'm not sure if they use different versions of Git. Just for clarity, was the repository a new clone in Desktop, then you opened the repository with Team Explorer? Had it ever been cloned in Team Explorer before?

Comment: Repo is a new clone from the GitHub Desktop application that was subsequently opened in Visual Studio 2013.  Never tried to clone from Team Explorer before.